# Getting the selected result from jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete, and I'm having a few issues with it. Here's what I have now:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var agencyData = [];
        agencyData.push({value: '1', label: 'Agency1'});  
        agencyData.push({value: '2', label: 'Agency2'});
        agencyData.push({value: '3', label: 'Agency3'});

        $(".agenciesTextbox").autocomplete({
            source: agencyData,
            minChars: 1,
            delay: 0
        });

    });

</script>
```

I have two problems with this:

1. When I select an item in the autocomplete list, it populates the textbox with the value and not the label (ie I selected Agency2 and the textbox populated with 2). How can I make it so that the textbox is populated with the label text?
2. I'd like to store the selected value in a hidden value - how can I capture the selected value when I choose an item?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".agenciesTextbox").autocomplete({
        source: agencyData,
        select: function (event, ui) {
           alert(ui.item.value)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkLY9/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var agencyData = [];
    agencyData.push({
        value: '1',
        label: 'Agency1'
    });
    agencyData.push({
        value: '2',
        label: 'Agency2'
    });
    agencyData.push({
        value: '3',
        label: 'Agency3'
    });

    $(".agenciesTextbox").autocomplete({

        source: agencyData,
        minChars: 1,
        delay: 0,
        focus: function (a, b) {
            $(".agenciesTextbox").val(b.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (a, b) {
            console.log(b.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, take a look at the fiddle, pretty straight forward. Remove the hidden tag off the val input and you'll notice it populate with the value.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzQw6/6/)

```
<input class="agenciesTextbox">
<input type="hidden" class="agenciesTextbox-val">

   $(document).ready(function () {

        var agencyData = [];
        agencyData.push({value: '1', label: 'Agency1'});  
        agencyData.push({value: '2', label: 'Agency2'});
        agencyData.push({value: '3', label: 'Agency3'});

        $(".agenciesTextbox").autocomplete({
            source: agencyData,
            minChars: 1,
            delay: 0,
            select: function( event, ui ) {                 
                $(".agenciesTextbox").val( ui.item.label );                 
                $(".agenciesTextbox-val").val( ui.item.value );                 
                return false;             
            }   
        });

    });
```